# Proposing a change to JavaScript itself?

Tags: javascript

I am aware of this site:

http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php

However, I have not been able to find where one would go to offer a proposed change to the JavaScript language.  Is doing so even open to the community at large?  Finally, does the mentioned site provide a comprehensive list of proposals.  I'll do a little research.  I'd hate to suggest something for which a similar proposal was already made.

Comment: Existing proposals can be found in the [harmony](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proposals) and [strawman](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:strawman) namespaces.

Comment: *"...does the mentioned site provide a comprehensive list of proposals..."* It's right there on the page you linked.

Comment: OK.  I thought I probably had the right page, but how would I add a new proposal?  I must be missing it.

Comment: I really doubt that they have an easy route for public proposals. Probably helps to have established yourself as a knowledgeable and highly respected ECMAScript programmer. By then you're probably familiar with all the right people. But if you do happen to find a way, your proposal should be very thoroughly presented. Also, probably best to not refer to it as the *"javascript language"* when making a proposal for ECMAScript.

Comment: @Mario, you can try to reach out to the people working on the ES specification through the mailing lists mentioned on [this](http://www.ecmascript.org/community.php) page.

Comment: @Mario, if you have understood how to make a proposal, please write some instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discussions for ECMAscript (old and new proposals): https://mail.mozilla.org/listinfo/es-discuss

Discussions for ECMAscript 5 only (erratas): https://mail.mozilla.org/listinfo/es5-discuss

Comment: Please consider lurking a bit and getting a feel of how discussions go before proposing a change. Also, please come with _problems_ and _use cases_ you want to address rather than solutions first.